ArduinoJson - how to merge two arrays into one?
How can I merge two JSON documents into one?
JSONDocument doc1;
JSONDocument doc2;

doc1["test"]["a"]["b"]="1";
doc1["test"]["a"]["c"]="2";

doc2["test"]["a"]["d"]="3";
doc2["test"]["a"]["c"]="4";

merged doc should be something like a result of such assignments:
doc["test"]["a"]["b"]="1";
doc["test"]["a"]["d"]="3";
doc["test"]["a"]["c"]="4";

As you see I am tring to "add" two variables doc1 and doc2 to achieve a json which will have elements from both doc1 and doc2 together in 1 json document. I was trying something like doc["test"].add(doc1["test"]) etc.
The background is that I am using ArduinoJson to create JSON with sensors data. The problem is that I have 2 sets of sensors, each returns own results. I cannot make ArduinoJson to combine those results into one single JSON document.
The code is:
    doc["test"]["dht"]=DHT11.getValuesJson();      // this is result from first sensors
    doc["test"]["dallas"]=DallasSensors.getValuesJson(); // result from other sensors
    // my attempts to create joined array with results from both sensor sets:
    doc["test"]["temp1"]=DallasSensors.getValuesJson();
    doc["test"]["temp1"].add(DHT11.getValuesJson());
    doc["test"]["temp2"].set(DallasSensors.getValuesJson());
    doc["test"]["temp2"].add(DHT11.getValuesJson());

The resulting data is as below. As you see I have two correct jsons, one from dht-temperature, another from dallas sensors, but the combined json has only data from dallas:
    "test": {
        "dht": {
            "temp": {
                "dht-temperature": "N.A."
            },
            "humidity": {
                "dht-humidity": "N.A."
            }
        },
        "dallas": {
            "temp": {
                "28388FD60B00003F": "27.69",
                "28EE60292E1601AE": "27.75",
                "28EEFA4B2E160133": "27.75",
                "28EED65D2E1601DB": "28.00",
                "28EE215C2E1601A3": "27.44",
                "28EE77562E1601B1": "27.56"
            }
        },
        "temp1": {
            "temp": {
                "28388FD60B00003F": "27.69",
                "28EE60292E1601AE": "27.75",
                "28EEFA4B2E160133": "27.75",
                "28EED65D2E1601DB": "28.00",
                "28EE215C2E1601A3": "27.44",
                "28EE77562E1601B1": "27.56"
            }
        },
        "temp2": {
            "temp": {
                "28388FD60B00003F": "27.69",
                "28EE60292E1601AE": "27.75",
                "28EEFA4B2E160133": "27.75",
                "28EED65D2E1601DB": "28.00",
                "28EE215C2E1601A3": "27.44",
                "28EE77562E1601B1": "27.56"
            }
        }

as you see ArduinoJson is totally ignoring any attempts to append data from second json to the first one. Both .add() and .set() functions seem to do nothing.
Expected result:
    "data": {
        "temp": {
            "28388FD60B00003F": "27.69",
            "28EE60292E1601AE": "27.75",
            "28EEFA4B2E160133": "27.75",
            "28EED65D2E1601DB": "28.00",
            "28EE215C2E1601A3": "27.44",
            "28EE77562E1601B1": "27.56",
            "dht-temperature": "ERROR"
        },
        "humidity": {
            "dht-humidity": "N.A."
        },

Can anybody help me with this? I am totally lost. I have already wasted more time on trying to do this with this library than with creating json manually.

Why do you want to do whatever you want to do at the receiving end, why not create the expected object at the sending end?

Please show the complete original json object you are dealing with, and the expect json object you want to achieve. None of the json objects you provided so far is a completed, valid json object.

@hcheung:

I cannot do this at sending end because jsons are coming from different sensor sets. each does not know about the others.
I know those are NOT complete jsons, above are only important parts relevant to the question
Having this clear what is the answer to the question itself?


We don't know what the original json object looks like, we only know a partial incomplete object, and your expected object is total different from what your code is doing, and with the limited code you show, we don't know your program logic and what you are trying to do with the code, so what do you want us to help you for?

Ok. I tried to make it very clear what I am trying to achieve in the question itself without digging too deep into code. I am simply trying to merge two json documents.

Ok. I found something like this, however I did not test it yet, there is a code discussing merging two JsonDocuments. It is using JsonVariant and not JsonDocument and I hope it will be possible to use it without large modifications for JsonDocument. It seems that the library ArduinoJSON itself is meant to be serialization/deserialization only library and there is no merge functionality.
void JSONmerge(JsonVariant dst, JsonVariantConst src)
{
   if (src.is<JsonObjectConst>())
   {
      for (JsonPairConst kvp : src.as<JsonObjectConst>())
      {
          if (dst[kvp.key()]) 
          merge(dst[kvp.key()], kvp.value());
      else
          dst[kvp.key()] = kvp.value();
      }
   }
   else
   {
      dst.set(src);
   }
}

To convert JsonDocument to JsonVariant it should be enough to do:
// create a variant
JsonVariant variant = doc.to<JsonVariant>();

